# AES256 encription Without RijndaelManaged in .Net core 1.1

Tags: c#, cryptography, aes, .net-core-1.1

I want to do AES256 Encryption in .net core 1.1. RijndaelManaged is not supporting with the .net core 1.1. So I'm using here `AES aes = new AES.create()`

This part of code create the random private key for the encryption

```
public string GenaratePassPharse()
    {
        RandomNumberGenerator rngCryptoServiceProvider = RandomNumberGenerator.Create();
        byte[] randomBytes = new byte[KEY_SIZE];
        rngCryptoServiceProvider.GetBytes(randomBytes);
        string plainPassPharse = Convert.ToBase64String(randomBytes);

        return plainPassPharse;
    }
```

and here the AES() encryption method. What I want to do is pass my generated key (which is return from above method)instead of the `aesAlg.Key` as an encryption key.

```
 static byte[] EncryptStringToBytes_Aes(string plainText, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
    {
        // Check arguments.
        if (plainText == null || plainText.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("plainText");
        if (Key == null || Key.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");
        if (IV == null || IV.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("IV");
        byte[] encrypted;

        // Create an Aes object
        // with the specified key and IV.
        using (Aes aesAlg = Aes.Create())
        {
            aesAlg.Key = Key;
            aesAlg.IV = IV;
            aesAlg.BlockSize = 128;
            aesAlg.KeySize = 128;



            // Create an encryptor to perform the stream transform.
            ICryptoTransform encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);

            // Create the streams used for encryption.
            using (MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    using (StreamWriter swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
                    {
                        //Write all data to the stream.
                        swEncrypt.Write(plainText);
                    }
                    encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray();
                }
            }
        }


        // Return the encrypted bytes from the memory stream.
        return encrypted;

    }
```

And any another way to use AES256 Encryption algorithms?

Comment: Unclear why you are doing `Convert.ToBase64String` while you use `byte[]` in the `EncryptStringToBytes_Aes`... What is your problem? Does it work?

Comment: Ok, Scenario is I need the create passwords for users as randomly and all password has the unique private key to decrypted that encrypted password. And That encrypted password stored in the database and generated private key stored in Azure

Comment: Azure key vault. Thats why I want pass created private key. key length should be 128. AES() does not provide set  key lenghth as 128

Comment: The `AES` class do support 128 bits and 256 bits key length...

Comment: So please can you provide the exapme.. I search the microsoft site but i didn't get any exaple for set key length

Comment: Ah no wait... With AES, if you have a 128bit key, you have AES128, if you have a 256bit key, you have AES256. You don't need to set the `BlockSize` and `KeySize` properties. The AES is "autosensing" based on the size of the key.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173549/discussion-between-namindu-sanchila-and-xanatos).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The full code should be:

```
public static byte[] EncryptStringToBytes_Aes(string plainText, byte[] key, byte[] iv = null)
{
    // Check arguments.
    if (plainText == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("plainText");
    }

    if (key == null || key.Length == 0)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");
    }

    // Create an Aes object
    // with the specified key and IV.
    using (Aes aes = Aes.Create())
    {
        aes.Key = key;

        if (iv == null)
        {
            iv = new byte[aes.BlockSize / 8];

            using (RandomNumberGenerator rngCryptoServiceProvider = RandomNumberGenerator.Create())
            {
                rngCryptoServiceProvider.GetBytes(iv);
            }
        }

        // Note that we are setting IV, Mode, Padding
        aes.IV = iv;
        aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

        // Create an encryptor to perform the stream transform.
        using (ICryptoTransform encryptor = aes.CreateEncryptor())
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
            // Prepend the IV
            cs.Write(iv, 0, iv.Length);

            // Here we are setting the Encoding
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(cs, Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                // Write all data to the stream.
                sw.Write(plainText);
            }

            byte[] encrypted = ms.ToArray();
            return encrypted;
        }
    }
}

public static string DecryptBytesToString_Aes(byte[] encrypted, byte[] key)
{
    // Check arguments.
    if (encrypted == null || encrypted.Length == 0)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("plainText");
    }

    if (key == null || key.Length == 0)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");
    }

    // Create an Aes object
    // with the specified key and IV.
    using (Aes aes = Aes.Create())
    {
        aes.Key = key;

        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(encrypted))
        {
            // Read the prepended IV
            var iv = new byte[aes.BlockSize / 8];
            ms.Read(iv, 0, iv.Length);

            // Note that we are setting IV, Mode, Padding
            aes.IV = iv;
            aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

            // Create an encryptor to perform the stream transform.
            using (ICryptoTransform decrytor = aes.CreateDecryptor())
            using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, decrytor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
            // Here we are setting the Encoding
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(cs, Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                // Read all data from the stream.
                string plainText = sr.ReadToEnd();
                return plainText;
            }
        }
    }
}

public static byte[] GenerateAesKey(int bits)
{
    using (RandomNumberGenerator rngCryptoServiceProvider = RandomNumberGenerator.Create())
    {
        byte[] key = new byte[bits / 8];
        rngCryptoServiceProvider.GetBytes(key);
        return key;
    }
}

public static void Main()
{
    var key = GenerateAesKey(256);
    var encrypted = EncryptStringToBytes_Aes("Hello", key);
    var decrypted = DecryptBytesToString_Aes(encrypted, key);
}
```

This code prepend a random IV to the encrypted stream, and the recovers it from the encrypted stream to decrypt the stream.

It is very important that when you speak of encryption you set everything that can be setted. There must be no questions open. The encryption `Mode`, the `Padding`, the `Encoding` the plaintext must be encoded. Everything!